# MVVM WPF Dividing the Views into Smaller Views

Tags: wpf, mvvm

How do you go about dividing the views into smaller views. Let's say I have a `Customer` object and each `Customer` can have `Order`s. Should I create a single view `CustomerOrderView` or should I create 3 views `CustomerOrderView`, `CustomerView`,  and `OrderView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view (or several views) for each ViewModel. In the `CustomerView`, you can then use `OrderView`s to display the orders in a `ItemsControl`

Comment: I guess the answer is that if we divide the Views into smaller views then we can reuse them later. Thanks!